# React Web App on Amazon Fire TV Stick shows up as Tablet Responsive

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, responsive, amazon-fire-tv

I created a React App where I also wanted to show a page on a mounted Television Screen.

The React APP Worked properly on a TV device but on an Amazon Fire Stick it is being shown as a Tablet Responsive screen rather than a large TV Screen (Desktop Style View)

Why is this the case?

I came across this in a documentation: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/customizing-your-web-app.html

But this still did not do the trick. My app and it's media queries are working properly on Desktop/Tablet/Mobile.